# Why this deque data structure thows read access violation

Tags: c++, access-violation, deque

I have homework from the university in which i have to use deque that is not from the std/stl library. I copied the code from my university guide book that they sold me but when i test it i get read access violation error. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct deque
{
    int key;
    deque *next_element;

} *LEFT = NULL, *RIGHT = NULL;

void push_LEFT(int x);
void push_RIGHT(int x);
int pop_LEFT(int &x);
int pop_RIGHT(int &x);

int main()
{
    int temp;
    push_LEFT(1);
    push_LEFT(2);
    push_LEFT(3);
    push_LEFT(4);

    pop_LEFT(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;
    pop_LEFT(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;
    pop_LEFT(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;
    pop_LEFT(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;
    system("pause");
}

void push_LEFT(int x)
{
    deque *ex;
    ex = LEFT;
    LEFT = new deque;
    LEFT->key = x;
    if (RIGHT == NULL)
    {
        RIGHT = LEFT; 
    }

}

void push_RIGHT(int x)
{
    deque *ex;
    ex = RIGHT;
    RIGHT = new deque;
    RIGHT->key = x;

    if (LEFT == NULL)
    {
        LEFT = RIGHT;
    }

    else
    {
        ex->next_element = RIGHT;
    }

}

int pop_LEFT(int &x)
{
    deque *ex;
    if (LEFT)
    {
        x = LEFT->key;
        ex = LEFT;
        LEFT = LEFT->next_element;
        if (LEFT == NULL)
        {
            RIGHT = NULL;
        }
        delete ex;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int pop_RIGHT(int &x)
{
    deque *ex;
    if (RIGHT)
    {
        x = RIGHT->key;
        if (LEFT == RIGHT)
        {
            delete RIGHT;
            LEFT = RIGHT = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            ex = LEFT;
            while (ex->next_element != RIGHT)
            {
                ex = ex->next_element;
            }
            x = RIGHT->key;
            ex->next_element = NULL;
            delete RIGHT;
            RIGHT = ex;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I think that the push functions work and the problem is in the pop functions because the exception is thrown there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes i'm very disappointed from the first year in the university.

Comment: `push_LEFT` never sets `next_element`, so the use in `pop_LEFT` cannot work at all.

Comment: What does this have to do with dynamic programming?

Comment: ... and `struct deque` is not even a double ended queue, it's just a singly linked list element.

Comment: No, don't burn books. Recycle them.

Comment: this example is completely wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your book example is completely wrong and it cant be correct with minor correction hence I wrote a new code for you. I think you are looking for a simple queue with push and pop methods. I wrote one direction queue or Left one in your code only and you can extend right one if you want.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct deque
{
    int key;
    deque *next_element=NULL;

} *LEFT = NULL;

void push_LEFT(int x);
void pop_LEFT(int &x);


int main()
{
    int temp;
    push_LEFT(1);
    push_LEFT(2);
    push_LEFT(3);
    push_LEFT(4);

    pop_LEFT(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;
    pop_LEFT(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;
    pop_LEFT(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;
    pop_LEFT(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;
    system("pause");
}

void push_LEFT(int x)
{

    if (LEFT== NULL)
    {
        LEFT = new deque;
        LEFT->key = x;
        LEFT->next_element = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        deque* ext=LEFT;
        while (ext->next_element!=NULL)
        {
            ext = ext->next_element;
        }
        ext->next_element = new deque;
        ext->next_element->key = x;
    }
}

void pop_LEFT(int &x)
{
    if (LEFT)
    {
        x = LEFT->key;
        delete Left; 
        LEFT = LEFT->next_element;
    }
}
```

Comment: @IvailoHristov please accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: @hamed you forgot delete the popped elements, therefore this implementation leaks memory.

Comment: @MichaelWalz you are right. I should free poped up elements. thank you